# Grails Domain Class Abstract/Non-Abstract Dynamic Check

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have a loop in my controller that does something like this:

```
for(d in grailsApplication.domainClasses) {
    def c = d.getClazz().count()

    // construct table containing object instance counts
}
```

My intent is to use this loop to count the instances of non-leaf domain classes in my database.  Is there a way to query the domain class itself to find out if it is abstract or not?  I wasn't sure if there were some member functions automatically added by the framework since I am still new to Groovy/Grails.  I couldn't find anything that addressed it in the Grails documentation.

Comment: Figured it out after a few minutes of poking around the Groovy documentation.  The function isAbstract() can be invoked on the domain class to determine whether or not the domain class is a leaf node in the class hierarchy.

Comment: you should reply your self with that as an answer and accept it.

Comment: I tried that but my reputation was too low to let me answer my own question in less than 8 hours.  Will give it another shot.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out after a few minutes of poking around the Groovy documentation. The function isAbstract() can be invoked on the domain class to determine whether or not the domain class is a leaf node in the class hierarchy